# Dailymotion : i want to play my private video in my android app through android sdk

Tags: android, video, dailymotion-api

I'm currently developing an android mobile app for an Education purposed , I want to play my private **dailymotion** video in side **dailymotion Android SDK** and i also read that private video will play  with private id but i did not understand from where i get this private id of video which i upload in dailymotion.

**"videoId (String) – A string representing a video ID – of the form xID (e.g. xwr14q) for public-accessible videos or kID (e.g. kABCD1234) for private-accessible videos."** from Dailymotion Document , here they mention that KID for private-accessible video.

so can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the private id of your videos directly in your [partner space](https://www.dailymotion.com/partner) in the share link of the video.
[image: DAilymotion private id position]
You can also get it using our [Data API](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/) by requesting the [`private_id`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#video-private_id-field) field however you must be connected to the API to request it. You can follow our [Authentication guide](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#authentication) to do so and test your request using our [API Explorer](https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/)

Last but not least, if you are already uploading through our API, you can directly retrieve the `private_id` during the video creation by specifying this field in your POST URL and it will be in the API response.

Example of video creation call returning private_id:

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
 -d 'url=<VIDEO_URL>' \
 -d 'title=Dailymotion cURL upload test' \
 -d 'private=true' \
 -d 'channel=school' \
 -d 'published=true' \
 "https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?fields=id,private_id,title"
```